# Memory pressure suddenly skyrockets and computer freezes or lags tremendously

Tags: safari, memory, performance

I've been getting this problem a lot and it's very frustrating. Sometimes, for no apparent reason, my MacBook will just freeze up or lag tremendously. The clock stops, apps stop responding, and it'll take a long time just to get a button to press. This usually happens when I'm watching a YouTube video in Safari.

When this happens, the memory pressure gets super-high in the Activity Monitor, and all "Safari Web Contents" and Safari itself are not responding. The Activity Monitor itself often freezes as well.

[image]
[image]

There is no high CPU usage when this happens. It's not overheating either. What could be the cause of this problem, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Are you watching Youtube with Flash or HTML5 video?

Comment: Your screenshot detail is not sufficient to give a good answer. If you have only 2 GB installed I would say that's normal, with 16 GB installed and only Safari running it would be alarming. Or: the graph may also show the "memory pressure" in my brain over time (the last 2 years in highschool and the first two years in university - the small bump in the red area were the first summer vacations).

Comment: Old Mac? replaced ram?
Please specify a bit more.